# Authencity of this hadith?

Tags: hadith

Rasulullah (Ssallallahu alaihi wa sallam) said: "Anyone who shaves has no claim to the mercy of Allah" - Reported by Ibn Abbas (RA) in Tibrabi'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Firstly***: The Hadith:

> من مثل بالشعر فليس له عند الله خلاق
>
> Whoever shaves the hair (off his face) he will not have any part of good/mercy with Allah

[المعجم الكبير](http://islamweb.org/newlibrary/display_book.php?bk_no=84&ID=2406&idfrom=10362&idto=12808&bookid=84&startno=402)

As for it's authenticity, it is weak (ضعيف) because in it is Hajjaj bin Nsir ( حجاج بن نصير) who is weak, [Source](http://shamela.ws/browse.php/book-12762/page-691#page-691).

***Secondly***: You confused me at first because I have never heard of someone called Tibrabi', so I guessed you were referring to Attabari (الطبري), but on an extended search I found that it is actually Attabarani (الطبراني) because he is the one who narrated the above hadith, so it is Attabarani (الطبراني) and not Tibrabi'.

Comment: So basically it's a weak hadith?

Comment: @user5212 Yes it is basically.